# Possible dividers of a number of three digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

1. For each natural number $n$ of $3$ decimal digits (thus with the first non-zero digit), we consider the number $n_0$ obtained by eliminating its possible digit equal to zero. For example, if $n = 205$ then $n_0 = 25$.
   Determine the number of three-digit integers $n$ for which $n_0$ is a divisor of $n$ other than $n$.
   I find a solution but my method of resolution is very large.
   Help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interesting ones are the ones of the form $n=100a+c$ with $a,c\in\{1,...,9\}$. Then
$$
10a+c\mid 100a+c\iff 10a+c\mid 90a
$$
so for some integer $k$ we must have
$$
90a=k(10a+c)\iff c=\frac{90a-10ak}{k}
$$
and to ensure $1\leq c\leq 9$ we must require
$$
\frac{90a}{10a+9}\leq k\leq\frac{90a}{10a+1}
$$
furthermore, $k$ has to divide $90a$ for $c$ to be an integer. It is then [easy to check](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20%5B90.0a%2F%2810a%2B9%29%2C90.0a%2F%2810a%2B1%29%5D%20for%20a%20from%201%20to%209) that
$$
\begin{align}
a&=1&&k\in\{5,6,7,8\}&5,6&\mid 90a\\
a&=2&&k\in\{7,8\}\\
a&=3&&k\in\{7,8\}\\
a&=4&&k\in\{8\}&8&\mid90a\\
a&=5&&k\in\{8\}\\
a&=6&&k\in\{8\}\\
a&=7&&k\in\{8\}\\
a&=8&&k\in\emptyset\\
a&=9&&k\in\emptyset
\end{align}
$$
so we are left with $(a,k,c)\in\{(1,5,8),(1,6,5),(4,8,5)\}$ so only
$$
\begin{align}
n&=108\\
n&=105\\
n&=405
\end{align}
$$
of the form $100a+c$ with $a,c\in\{1,2,...,9\}$ will work - and they do!
$$
\begin{align}
108/18&=6\\
105/15&=7\\
405/45&=9
\end{align}
$$

---

The less interesting cases are $a\mid 100a$ and naturally $100a+10b=10(10a+b)$ so $10a+b\mid100a+10b$.

Comment: My solution is equal.. Very well

Comment: @DomenicoVuono: It is slightly more elegant than trial and error for the $81$ cases of $a,c\in\{1,2,...,9\}$, but maybe not much faster. This has to do with the very limited character of the question "space" in the first place :)